# AngularJS - Data not pulling back from stored procedure into table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been given a legacy system to add new data to so I've copied from an existing table of data. The issue I'm having is it looks like the stored procedure is never firing on the app end (the others do fine).

I'm using a controller in the api folder to do the mssql query with the user ID.

```
/**
 * Get list of calls per user
*/
exports.list = function (req, res) {

    var conn = new mssql.Connection(config.mssql);
    conn.connect(function (err) {

        if (err) {
            if (err) return res.send(500, err);
        } else {

            var request = new mssql.Request();
            request.input('user', mssql.BigInt(8), req.user);
            request.execute('storedprocedurename', function (err, recordset) {
                if (err) {
                    res.status(500).json(err);
                }
                else {
                    res.status(200).json(recordset[0]);
                }
                conn.close();
            });
        }
    });

};
```

Routing the calls call..

```
//Added
router.get('/', auth.isAuthenticated(), noCache, controller.list);
//
router.post('/', auth.isAuthenticated(), controller.save, autoresponder.send);
```

Using the Call.Service.Js

```
.factory('Call', ['$http', '$q', function Call($http, $q) {

    var calls;

    return {
        /**
                 * Load all call data
                 *
                 */
        load: function (callback) {

            var cb = callback || angular.noop;
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get('/api/calls')
                .success(function (data) {
                    calls = data;
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                    return cb(data);
                })
                .error(function (err) {
                    deferred.reject(err);
                    return cb(err);
                }.bind(this));

            return deferred.promise;
        },
```

and then in my controller

```
.controller('CallCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$http', '$modal', '$log', 'Machine', 'Call', 'Auth',
        function ($scope, $location, $http, $modal, $log, Machine, Call, Auth) {

           
            $scope.calls = [];

            Call.load(function (data) {
                $scope.calls = data;
            });
```

Then my HTML. - One thing I'm not sure is the "Call in Calls" - Where is Call meant to be set? is this just an identifier for every line in the Calls Data array I've pulled back?

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th> Start Time</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="call in calls">
                <td ng-bind="call.StartedDateTime"> Test</td>
           </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: $scope.$apply(function () {
     $scope.calls = data;
});

Answer (score 0):

Try to use $apply when you set new value in scope

```
Call.load(function (data) {
  $scope.calls = data;
  if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply()
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer; unfortunately still looks like no data is being pulled through. Not sure if the answer lies in the api load.

Comment: if you add console.log() 
```
 Call.load(function (data) {
   console.log(data) 
   ...
 });
```
Do you see the data in console ?

Comment: I get "$digest already in progress" and "api/calls 404 (Not Found)"  - in my router folder  have  app.use('/api/calls', require('./api/call')); and it works totally fine for saving.

Comment: I have added by index to my rows as I was getting duplicates not allowed but I'm still getting 404 api not found.